# libgdx box2d interpolation doesn't work well

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx, interpolation

I am developing an Android game with libgdx and box2d.
My Problem is that the interpolation of the body in box2d doesn't work well... The body is laging a bit. The body is "less laging" without the interpolation. 
Here is the part of my code:

```
public void gameRunning()
{
    mAccumulator += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    if(mAccumulator > 1f)
    {
        mAccumulator = 1f;
    }

    while(mAccumulator >= BOX_STEP)
    {
        resetSmooth();
        mWorld.step(BOX_STEP, BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS);
        mAccumulator -= BOX_STEP;
    }

    mWorld.clearForces();
    smooth();
}

public void smooth()
{
    float ratio = mAccumulator/BOX_STEP;
    float oneMinusRatio = 1.f-ratio;

    mSmoothedX = ratio*mBowl.getPosition().x+oneMinusRatio*mPreviousX;
    mSmoothedY = ratio*mBowl.getPosition().y+oneMinusRatio*mPreviousY;

    mBowl.setTransform(mSmoothedX, mSmoothedY, 0f);
}

public void resetSmooth()
{
    mSmoothedX = mPreviousX; 
    mSmoothedY = mPreviousY; 

    mPreviousX = mBowl.getPosition().x;
    mPreviousY = mBowl.getPosition().y;
}
```

Where is the problem?
Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance... :)

Comment: why the `if(mAccumulator > 1f)` block?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt move box2d bodies like that, apply forces/impulses instead. They won't behave correctly in the physics simulation otherwise.

Also, your Interpolation implementations seems very weird to me, why do you not use the [Interpolation class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Interpolation.html).

Example:

```
    mSmoothedX = Interpolation.linear.apply(startx, endx, <time>);
```